# Google Script for Spreadsheet : How to keep value saved for "ever"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a Google Script for my Spreadsheets, and the script queries an external API that requires payment every time it is queried.

I'd like my script to keep in memory the value if it has been already loaded (meaning if I didn't changed the other cells used by this script), in order to avoid querying the API every time I load the page.

I thought about using the Cache, especially the `CacheService.getDocumentCache()`, but it's not a long term storage.

Is there a better alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a spreadsheet itself as long-term storage. Save the parameters used and the return values there and check it every time before querying your external API.

If it's not too much data, the [Properties Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) may also suit you. But if it's "too much" data it'll not work. Well, even a Spreadsheet has some constraints. In such case, you could try using a regular file in Google Drive as storage or an [external database via JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

But if you need to get there your script will probably start hitting [other Apps Script quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) that may prevent you to use it at all.

Comment: Interesting. A solution I could use is to query for one more parameter, that will be used to output the result (errors for example). If that cell is empty, the search wouldn't have never been done. Is that a good solution?

Comment: I took a look at Properties Services but I believe it won't work (too many data to save). The JDBC alternative will be too complicated to set up (for my users). :/

Comment: Well, I've also suggested saving a file in Drive, which seems to be a good fit for you. Kriggs [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29218208/222901) have exemplified it with code.

Answer (score 1):

A bit faster than SpreadsheetApp is to save as a JSON in Google Drive:

```
function saveFile(){
  var transactions = {'ben@gmail.com ': 1238190238, 'dora@gmail.com' : 1238190238, 'ksd@gmail.com' : 1238190238};
  return DriveApp.createFile('Transactions', JSON.stringify(transactions ));
}

function getFile(){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Transactions').next();
  return JSON.parse(file.getAs("application/none").getDataAsString());
}
```